# vue-router@4.0.11 can't match route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I've the following route passed to vue-router:

```js
{
  path: "/(lat/:lat/lng/:lng)?",
  meta: { private: true }
}
```

It should match `/`, or `/lat/1/lng/2`. But, when I try to start the web app at `/`, the page gets stuck in an infinite loop, throwing the warning `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/"`.

Any idea why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong, or is it a vue-router issue?

**Note**: I've tried to use aliases, and set the route alias to `"/(lat/:lat/lng/:lng)?"`, it works, but it throws the warning: `[Vue Router warn]: Alias "/lat/:lat/lng/:lng" and the original record: "/" should have the exact same param named "lat"`